# Canadian Greyhound - is there a charge for bringing an extra snowboard?

Tags: canada, luggage, winter-sports, greyhound

I've bought a ticket from Vancouver to Calgary, and will have my backpack (checked luggage) and a day pack on the bus.

I'm considering bringing my snowboard as well. However, 1) I don't have a bag for it and 2) I'm not sure if it'd cost me extra to do so.

It didn't mention it in the terms and conditions when buying, and the only thing related was a mention of skipoles not being allowed onboard.

**Can anyone find information on whether a bagless snowboard is permitted as checked luggage, and how much it would cost in addition to the regular fare?**

Comment: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_a_Skateboard_allowed_on_the_greyhound

Comment: That answer covers bringing a *skateboard* ON the bus, rather than being charged for checking a *snowbard* :/

Answer (score 2):

I think these rules are very dependent on the bus terminal and the line.

First, Vancouver-Calgary is a part of the transcontinental line. So a lot of people are moving with a lot of stuff. From the little I saw, they are cool with everyone bringing random things such as guitars and even a bicycle, but I would not say it's always the case.

For the terminal, I remember they were nice in Toronto, not even checking the number of bags. In Calgary, however, they charged 10 bucks for each extra or oversized bag.

Know that they also have [a shipping service in Canada](http://www.shipgreyhound.com/), so they make money out of this.

All that said, I would recommend you to directly go to the terminal and ask about their policies, to know if it is cheaper to buy a snowboard bag or pay a fee or if you are just lucky.

Answer (score 1):

From my experiences with greyhound, they usually don't mind a skateboard/snowboard if there is plenty of space in the cargo hold. This also applies to luggage exceeding usually allowed size.

Comment: A snowboard (mine is 157cm) is generally considerably longer than a skateboard, which is what concerns me :/

Comment: The 'usually' is the problem, I can just see it being this time that they get upset ;)